# NameError: name 'Automobile' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x

Not sure why I am getting NameError: name 'Automobile' is not defined.
Maybe someone who hasn't been staring at this for the past 20 minutes can help out. I am starting to think it might be the indention, but not too sure yet.

vehicles.py:

```
class Automobile:

    def __init__(self, make, model, mileage, price):
        self.__make = make
        self.__model = model
        self.__mileage = mileage
        self.__price = price

    def set_make(self, make):
        self.__make = make

    def set_model(self, model):
        self.__model = model

    def set_mileage(self, mileage):
        self.__mileage = mileage

    def set_price(self, price):
        self.__price = price

    def get_make(self):
        return self.__make

    def get_model(self):
        return self.__model

    def get_mileage(self):
        return self.__mileage

    def get_price(self):
        return self.__price

    class Car(Automobile):

        def __init__(self, make, model, mileage, price, doors):

            Automobile.__init__(self, make, model, mileage, price)

            self.__doors = doors

        def set_doors(self, doors):
            self.__doors = doors

        def get_doors(self):
            return self.__doors
```

car_demo.py:

```
import vehicles

def main():
    used_car = vehicles.Car("Audi", 2007, 12500, 21500.00, 4)

    print('Make:', used_car.get_make())
    print('Model:', used_car.get_model())
    print('Mileage:', used_car.get_mileage())
    print('Price:', used_car.get_price())
    print('# of doors:', used_car.get_doors())

main()
```

Error:

```
Traceback:
import vehicles, class Automobile:, and class Car(Automobile)

NameError: name 'Automobile' is not defined
```

I would've thought setting Automobile as a class defines 'Automobile'
Any help would be appreciated.

I am using Python 3.5.2 IDLE

Comment: try use `from vehicles import automobile` and then access the car class

Comment: Did you mean to indent the Car class inside of Automobile ?

Comment: @Bobby No dice. Still getting same error.

Comment: Which error? Please include complete error message with traceback (or would it be too easy then ;-P) Ah, and correct the indentation in your question.

Comment: @denvaar I really want to rip my hair out right now. Did not catch that. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @LimaBEAN those python gotchas. XD

Comment: @mkiever Post seemed a bit too long already. Didn't want to overload. denvaar caught it though. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you didn't mean to indent the `Car` class inside of `Automobile`. You should un-indent that class one level, and instead of:

```
Automobile.__init__(self, make, model, mileage, price)
```

you should use:

```
super(Car, self).__init__(make, model, mileage, price)
```

And if you're using Python 3, you can just do:

```
super().__init__(make, model, mileage, price)
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Actually, given it's Python 3 code, even better would be: `super().__init__(make, model, mileage, price)`. No-arg `super` is nice.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Thanks for the edit. I was debating if I should put traceback in the code block or not. Looks much cleaner.